# Running a .exe file from a Java web app doesn't work

Tags: java, tomcat8

I'm trying to run a .exe file develop in Pascal from my web app(Windows + Primefaces 5 + Tomcat 8). The program generate a text file that I'm gonna read it after but it seems it doens't have the permission to do that, no exceptions were threw.

Here is how I pick the path:

```
String path = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/lib/");
projeto.setQtde(1);
this.esquemas = gerenciarProjeto.realizarCorte(projeto, usuario, path+"/");
```

and here is how I call the program:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pc = rt.exec(this.caminho+"cortebi.exe");

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(pc.getErrorStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
System.out.println("<ERROR>");

while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
  System.out.println(line);
}

System.out.println("</ERROR>");
int exitVal = pc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

I realized that if I put the .exe file into my project root and run Eclipse as administrator it works. But I do not know how to put it into my web app root to do the same after it's deployed, I've tried to put it in diferent locations and nothing!

Comment: Will your application be running on `Windows` with `Admin` privileges ?

Comment: In fact I don't know, it's for a local university here and things aren't so clear. If I could give write privileges to the .exe file I thing it would be enought.

Comment: I asked because you will probably not be able to run the `exe` file on Linux. Otherwise you can just embed the executable file with the WAR save it to temporary directory and execute it using Java ProcessBuilder. However this will only work if the container was started with Admin privilege, that's probably not going to be the case because of the security reasons. Why do you want to execute exe anyway?

Comment: Might be better if your executable just wrote to stdout instead - you can pipe that wherever you need it without messing with file permissions.

Comment: .exe file is a Pascal legacy code written to solve linear programming problems I can't change it in any form. The way that the legacy code works is reading text files and creating an output text file with the answer. I'm able to create the files that are needed to the .exe but the .exe itself can't write the answers files.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, since in stackoveflow, solutions are posted as answers and you can and are even encouraged to answer your own questions as you can. So please create an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what was the problem. I tought that Runtime.getRuntime().exec() would behave like a tradicional DOS prompt but I was wrong. In fact the problem itself was not a windows or file permission problem but a misconception of how the exec() method works. I wrote a new piece of code:

```
public void executarCortebi(File file){
    try {

        Process pc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cortebi.exe",null, file);          

        StreamGobbler error = new StreamGobbler(pc.getErrorStream(), "ERRO");

        StreamGobbler output = new StreamGobbler(pc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");


        error.start();
        output.start();

        pc.waitFor();

        Thread.sleep(800);  

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(InterruptedException e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As I said the way the exec() method works is more restricted I found good material here:[When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).
Explaining the parameters of getRuntime.exec() used for me, we have the fallow: First the command itself that must be executed(It's noticeable the diferences between the old cold and the new one), second are the arguments for the .exe file wich in this case are none and third is the file that has the path from my .exe program. 
Now everything is working!